# virtualbox private networks, port forwarding, etc

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have a Virtual Box appliance that I imported for Testia Tarantula. The box is a CentOs install with a rails application running on it.

All I want to do is set up the box so that I can access the rails server from the browser on my host machine. I've done stuff like this with vagrant before, and it was a snap, but things don't seem to be working for me now. I'm in a corporate environment with Windows, firewalls, etc.

How do I set up VirtualBox so that I can access ports and ips from my host?

Comment: using host only now. I'm able to ping the machine. When I try to access the server from the host machine's browser, though, I get a GATEWAY_TIMEOUT message.

Comment: The host only network is in effect a second network that your host machine is attached to, depending on the settings of your main (windows corporate) network you may need to adjust things like routes, name resolution etc. Try adding the name and IP for your VM to the host machine's hosts-file, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the correct **network mode**.

[image: Virtualbox network settings]

Use either Bridged Adapter (if you want your guest to be accessible to all machines on the network, not just the host) or Host-only Adapter (if you want only the host to be able to access the VM).

Read more about it here: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html